# In App Purchase subscriptions work for me in testing / Test Flight, but not for App Review team

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I am dealing with a very frustrating App rejection. Apple has twice rejected my App with **Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness**. They're stating that the In App Purchase (an auto-renew subscription) is not unlocking the premium content after the purchase is made.

I have thoroughly tested this IAP on my end, on 3 devices, and 3 different TestFlight accounts. All tests worked flawlessly. I am unable to replicate the issue the Apple App review team is having.

The same IAP helper / receipt validation is also being used in another App of mine that has been working perfect for well over a year on the App Store.

- I have ensured all product identifiers match up.
- I have re-generated a Subscription Secret.

**Is there anything I may be overlooking?** What may cause the IAP to not unlock the content for JUST the App reviewer, and not any of my 6 unique devices that were tested and work perfect.

Comment: Have you consider `sandbox` and `production` mode?

Comment: @DuyNguyen - Yes. In my receipt validation I handle status 21007, which covers sandbox to production

Comment: The build that Apple is reviewing is point to production right?

Comment: @DuyNguyen - Yes. It's pointing to production

Answer (score 2):

This has been resolved! My App was using `expires_date` in the receipt validation for the in-app subscription. It turns out, `expires_date` is bug-prone in certain configurations of devices (device / ios / locale). Because of this, the purchase was successfully finishing, but the premium content was remaining locked due to a misconfigured expiry date.

**The solution was to use `expires_date_ms` instead of `expires_date`. It doesn't even look like expires_date is documented anymore on Apple's docs.**

See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/expires_date_ms

Hope this helps anybody running into issues of in-app purchase subscriptions not unlocking content!